# oSettings is null when calling fnPagingInfo function

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc, datatable, jstl

I'm currently trying to solve a problem with my table.

I'm using JSTL to print an object list inside an object from my controller, displaying the result in multiple tables.

Everything is working well until I apply the datatable function in my javascript, resulting in `Cannot read property '_iDisplayStart of null` and when I check the function `$.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnPagingInfo`it appears that the oSettings is null.

This is my javascript code:

```
var oInit ={
            'sDom': "<'datatables-action-box'<'span6 link-tabla'r><'span18 link-tabla'l>>t<'datatables-action-box'<'span2 link-tabla'i><'span2'p>>",
            'bAutoWidth': false,
            'bFilter': false, 
            'bLengthChange': true,
            'iDisplayLength': 10,
            'aLengthMenu': [1, 5, 10, 15, 50, 100],
            'sPaginationType': 'bootstrap',
            'aoColumns': aoColumns,
            'oLanguage': oLanguage,
            'aaSorting': [[2,'desc']] 
    };

    $('table#tabla_paginada_obtener_portales').dataTable(oInit); 

    var buttonCustom = $("#buttonCustom");
    var buttonPlaceholder = $(".dataTables_rango");
    buttonPlaceholder.html(buttonCustom);
```

This is my jsp:

```
<c:if test="${not empty portals}">
    <c:forEach var="bloque" items="${portals.blocs}">
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${not empty bloque.items}">
                <table id="tabla_paginada_obtener_portales" class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Title</th>
                            <th>Description</th> 
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <c:forEach var="item" items="${bloque.items}">
                        <c:if test="${not empty item }">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><c:out value="${item.titol}" /></td>
                                    <td><c:out value="${item.descripcio}" /></td>

                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </c:if>
                    </c:forEach>
                </table>
                <br>
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                <spring:message code="checklist.obtenerPortal.tabla.noresult" />
                <br>
                <br>
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
    </c:forEach>
</c:if>
```

As you can see, I have an object called **portals** that has a object list called **blocs**, and when this object is not empty I create a for each that print the table equal the times it has **items**, then I print the item list contents. Its a list inside an object.

I don't know if it because there are multiple tables in the view page or I'm missing something else. what could I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to get to the solution, it was pretty simple, the problem was in the JSP, the tag  has to be outside the for each function.

Like this:

```
<tbody>
    <c:forEach var="item" items="${bloque.items}">
        <c:if test="${not empty item }">
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${item.titol}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${item.descripcio}" /></td>
            </tr>
        </c:if>
    </c:forEach>
</tbody>
```

tag is used to group the body content in an HTML table, inside a For each the datatable can't make the pagination because it repeats constaly and the code mess up.